# Вытащить маршрут из NavigationEnd

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

```
this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(
        x => {
          console.log('val',x);
          this.redUrl = x['url'];
          console.log(this.redUrl);
          return this.redUrl;
        }
      )
```

Данный код хранится в функции при её вызове все консоль логи и т.д. срабатывает, но присвоив отловленный маршрут this.redUrl - заранее объявленная переменная выше constructor, - так я хотел вывести маршрут наружу, при попытке вывести переменную приходит undefined, а внутри функции присваивается.

P.S. Надеюсь хорошо описал проблему

Comment: `subscribe` возвращает инстанс `Subscription`, а не `this.redUrl`, к тому же весь жизненный цикл роутера полностью асинхронный + проблему вы не описали, `заранее объявленная переменная выше constructor, - так я хотел вывести маршрут наружу` - это не описание, я не понимаю что это

Comment: В общем я просто хочу получить маршрут который ввёл и вывести его в переменную, чтобы потом получить данный url в любом месте

Comment: вы можете просто взять `location.pathname`, это одно и то же

Comment: и я уверен что вы получаете `undefined` потому что делаете `console.log` еще до того как переменной присваивается значение